# Send endorsement message after finding new block Go Ethereum

Tags: go-ethereum

When miner successfully found a new block's nonce, it then seal this block and broadcast/announce to peers in network. I want to add endorsement feature after miner found a nonce. This requires sending a message to all peers in the network. Trusted peers receive a message, then reply back to miner. Then, miner continue on committing, and broadcasting. 
go-ethereum/consensus/ethash.go:

```
default:
        // We don't have to update hash rate on every nonce, so update after after 2^X nonces
        attempts++
        if (attempts % (1 << 15)) == 0 {
            ethash.hashrate.Mark(attempts)
            attempts = 0
        }
        // Compute the PoW value of this nonce
        digest, result := hashimotoFull(dataset.dataset, hash, nonce)
        if new(big.Int).SetBytes(result).Cmp(target) <= 0 {
            // Correct nonce found, create a new header with it
            logger.Trace("Nonce was found at this time", "attempts", nonce-seed, "nonce", nonce)
            time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)

            header = types.CopyHeader(header)
            header.Nonce = types.EncodeNonce(nonce)
            header.MixDigest = common.BytesToHash(digest)

            ethash.passEndorse = false
            if (ethash.passEndorse){
                select {
                case found <- block.WithSeal(header) :
                    logger.Trace("Ethash nonce found and reported", "attempts", nonce-seed, "nonce", nonce)
                case <-abort:
                    logger.Trace("Ethash nonce found but discarded", "attempts", nonce-seed, "nonce", nonce)
                }
                nonce++
            }else {
                logger.Trace("Nonce found but discarded", "attempts", nonce-seed, "nonce", nonce)
                logger.Trace("Wait 15s before starting new search")
             // calling function from go-ethereum/eth/tracers/handler.go
             // to send message to peers
             // handler.go takes care of broadcasting and announcing block 
             // to peers
                eth.sendEndorseMessage("foo")
            }
            break search
```

However, adding import "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth" will give error "import cycle not allowed". Is there anyway to avoid import cycle? Or Should I create the function somewhere else and how to invoke it?

Comment: this is not an Ethereum question, you have created circular dependency by adding this import, and `Golang` doesn't allow circular dependencies https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28256923/import-cycle-not-allowed

Comment: also, why would you notify that you found a nonce if you can just send the entire block to other miners, I don't see logic here.

Comment: the reason is to avoid 51% attack. At early stage, a group of miners (51%) could take advantage of this to create a fake blockchain.